# java jdb does not display code lines in step output

Tags: java, jdb

Trying to learn the jdb from the command line.  From tutorials I expect to see the code line output when I step lines, but I am not.

Here is sample code I compiled:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        System.out.println("Hello world! line 2");
        System.out.println("Hello world! line 3");
    }
}
```

```
$ ~/jdk-18.0.2.1/bin/jdb.exe Main
Initializing jdb ...
> stop at Main.main
Deferring breakpoint Main.main.
It will be set after the class is loaded.
> run
run Main
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
>
VM Started: Set deferred breakpoint Main.main

Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", Main.main(), line=3 bci=0

main[1] step
> Hell
Step completed: o world!
"thread=main", Main.main(), line=4 bci=8

main[1] step
> Hello world! line 2

Step completed: "thread=main", Main.main(), line=5 bci=16

main[1]
```

Note, in here, the output is showing, but I expect to see the code lines that are about to be executed, and the line number displayed, like:

```
3       System.out.println("Hello world!");
```

I've seen tutorials that have screen shots with this happening, and I am wondering if I have a missing setting or a wrong version of jdb or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the option list to show the lines around your current position

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "use the option list"?  Is it a command issued in the debugger?

Comment: yes, see https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~horwitz/jdb/jdb.html

Answer (score 1):

Ran into same issue when debugging android app within AVD. I was not able to list sourcecode even if I defined the correct `-sourcepath`.

I need to execute JDB from correct directory. If the class belongs to any package, e.g. class `MainActivity` belongs to package `org.gradle.samples`, then your project folder contains the following directory:

```
yourProject/
├── src
│   └── main
│       └── java
│           └── org
│               └── gradle
│                   └── samples
│                       └── MainActivity.java
```

Then you have to execute `jdb` from `<pathToYourProject>/src/main/java`, where JDB `-sourcepath` is `<pathToYourProject>/src/main/java` as well.